# Las Vegas: Best casino for 1-2 no limit?

Tags: live, casino, skill

I would like to know where an intermediate player stands a chance of not losing their shirt playing 1-2 cash game in Vegas. :) What would be your choice for a casino?

Comment: losing their shirt?

Comment: an English expression meaning "beaten badly" and "going broke".

Comment: Cheers from across the pond.

Comment: @Svisstack must be some form of strip poker ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MGM Grand is my favorite recommendation for first timers. The action is consistently soft, and they cater to 1/2 games.

Other rooms are bigger and perhaps fancier, but they also tend to attract a more aggressive, more skilled player. if you are worried about losing your shirt, I would stay away from the likes of Aria, Venetian, Bellagio and wynn. I would also avoid the smaller and local rooms as they tend to have a lot off regular and professional players. One exception to this is Mandalay Bay.its a small room but for some reason they attract a lot of drunk tourists.

Comment: make me laugh with the drunk tourists

Comment: Everything was true

Comment: How did you do?

Comment: If that the case then why don't all the pros just go to MGM  and make a fortune?